# AHK says invalid hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My AHK script says that `numpad3` or `3` is invalid, what is the code I must input to make my script input numbers?

```
F9::
    Toggle := !Toggle
     While Toggle{
        3
        sleep 10
        4
        sleep 10
        5
        sleep 1000
    }
return
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `Send` command. `Send {3}` or `Send {Numpad3}` [Send Keys & Clicks](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

Comment: Does that make it work correctly?